# UL menu won't display after using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you resize the page down to 600 pixels it should get rid of the menu and place a menu button which you can click. Click it at least once and then close the menu, then resize the page so it's over 600 pixels, and the menu won't come up anymore. Why is this happening?

```css
*{
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Verdana, "Segoe UI", Arial;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
}
body{
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
background: #ddd;
}
a{
color: darkblue;
font-weight: bold;
}

.logo{
width: 60%;
max-width: 335px;
max-height: 50px;
vertical-align: center;
}
.menuicon{
width: 80%;
max-width: 20px;
}

header img{
max-height: 50px;
}
header{
height: 50px;
background: #222;
color: white;
}
.menu{
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #222;
border-bottom: solid 1px #111;
z-index: 10;

}
.menu li {
float: left;
}

.menu li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #444;
}

.menu li a.active {
color: white;
background-color: #0abee6;
}

.ulimg{
float: right;
padding: 10px !important;
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.ulimg{
    display: block;
}
.menu{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-top: none;
}
.menu li{
    float: none;
}

.menu li a {
    text-align: left;
    }

.menu li:last-child a{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
}
```

```css
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/MashyIndustriesLongTrans.png" class="logo">
        <a class="ulimg" href"#lol"><img src="images/menu.png"  onclick="toggle_visibility('panel')" class="menuicon"/></a>
    </header>
    <ul id="panel" class="menu">
        <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="investors.html">Investors</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
</body
```

Comment: This is off-topic as it stands, for more info, please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Will fix it right now

Comment: provide some code to explain what you have tried etc

Comment: I've tried 

`@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
 .menu{
        display: block !important;
        }
}`

Comment: This doesn't work, It stops the javascript from even opening the menu when it goes down to 600 pixels I don't understand why. Shouldn't the media only be happening when page becomes 600 pixels or more?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've edited the question better